# Linear search algorithm template implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm

This template class is a linear search algorithm with a simple search function. I have tested it with `int` and `char` and it seems to be working fine. I would like pointers on how I can make it more efficient and on my coding technique. I do know that the standard library provides this algorithm, i am just doing it for fun and practice

sLinear.h

```
//Linear search template

#ifndef SLINEAR_H
#define SLINEAR_H

namespace fm
{
    template <typename T>
    class sLinear
    {
        T *_list;
        T _item;
        int _sizeOfList;

    public:
        sLinear();
        sLinear(T *myArray, T item, int size);

        ~sLinear();

        int findItem();

    };


    //------public methods------
    template <typename T>
    sLinear<T>::sLinear()
    {
        _list = nullptr;
        _sizeOfList = 0;
    }

    template <typename T>
    sLinear<T>::sLinear(T *myArray, T item, int size)
    {
        _list = myArray;
        _item = item;
        _sizeOfList = size;
    }

    template <typename T>
    sLinear<T>::~sLinear()
    {
        _list = nullptr;
        _sizeOfList = 0;
    }

    template <typename T>
    int sLinear<T>::findItem()
    {
        while (_list != nullptr)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _sizeOfList; i++)
            {
                if (_list[i] == _item)
                {
                    return i + 1;
                }

            }

            return -1;

        }
    }
}
#endif
```

main.h

```
#include<iostream>
#include "sLinear.h"

using namespace fm;


int main()
{

    /* Linear search with integer */
    int iList[] = { 1,9,2,6,5,3,7,4,8,0 };
    int size = (sizeof(iList) / sizeof((iList[0])));

    sLinear<int> mySearch(iList, 8, size);
    int k = mySearch.findItem();

    if (k == -1)
        std::cout << "Item not found!" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Item found:" << k << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Returning `int` is dubious; it unnecessarily narrows the range of possible return values. Consider retuning an iterator.
- The line `if (_list[i] == _item)` implies that `_list` must provide an `operator[](int)`, which is very restrictive. A linear search is just like its name implies, linear. It is expected to work on any *linear* collection, e.g. forward iterator (maybe even on input iterator).
- The `class sLinear` exposes one public method, and keeps no state. There's no reason to make it a class. A standalone

  ```
  template <typename I>
  I findItem(I first, I last, I::value_type value) {
      ....
  }
  ```

  will do as well.
- `while (_list != nullptr)` is very strange. `_list` never changes; why do you want to loop?

  PS: Could you explain a rationale for returning `i+1`?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am returning i+1 because in arrays index starts from 0, but most people read from 1.

Comment: @dirty_feri Programmers read from 0. Non-programmers will hardly use your code.

Comment: good point, I will implement the change.

Comment: @vnp, it would be great to use `std::iterator_traits<I>::value_type`, since it will work for pointers as well.

Comment: Also missing `typename` will cause compilation error :)